# Why does Objective-C use YES and NO instead of 1 and 0?

Tags: objective-c

Is there any technical reason why Objective-C uses YES and NO instead of 1 and 0, or is it simply to make it more readable?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
typedef signed char        BOOL; 
// BOOL is explicitly signed so @encode(BOOL) == "c" rather than "C" 
// even if -funsigned-char is used.
#define OBJC_BOOL_DEFINED


#define YES             (BOOL)1
#define NO              (BOOL)0
```

(For reference)

```
[button setAttr:YES];
```

Sounds nicer IMHO then...

```
[button setAttr:TRUE];
```

Answer (score 57):

Making it more readable *is* a technical reason.

Answer (score 27):

[C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_datatype#C) (on which Objective-C is based) didn't have a boolean type until C99.

[Objective-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C) was created in the 80s and defined it's own boolean type.

Comment: `Objective-C` is _so 80's chic_.

Answer (score 22):

Because the programmer *means* **yes** and **no**, not **1** and **0**.

Answer (score 9):

The same reason *most* languages use `true` and `false`... You can use 1 and 0 if you like, same as any of those other languages.

Really, if you think about it, we're talking about:

```
#define YES 1
#define NO  0
```

It's simply nicer to read.

Comment: you can still use true/false in objective-c

Comment: Am I the ONLY one that ***constantly*** gets tripped up by this...  I grew up in the `bash` shell.. where `0`... "means good", _aka_ *YES!*... á la `exit 0`...  Every time I use a `C` `boolean` I have to *force* my mind to accept this paradoxical reality!

Comment: @alexgray I am a "Bash"-ist too. A way to remember is: 

"It is **true** that bash shell executed correctly when there is **0** error (ie 0 == true in Bash) and while everything else think there is **1** error (ie 1 == true in non Bash language)"

Answer (score 3):

It's just syntax, there's no technical reason for it. They just use YES/NO for their BOOL instead of true/false like c++ does.

Comment: Down-voted because this does not answer the question.