# Is comparing a BOOL against YES dangerous?

Tags: objective-c, boolean, comparison

I found a comment today in a source file:

```
//  - no longer compare BOOL against YES (dangerous!)
```

Is comparing `BOOL` against `YES` in Objective-C really that dangerous? And why is that?

Can the value of `YES` change during runtime? Maybe `NO` is always `0` but `YES` can be `1`, `2` or `3` - depending on runtime, compiler, your linked frameworks?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690903/why-does-objective-c-use-yes-and-no-instead-of-1-and-0

Comment: BTW, in 64-bit iOS targets, `BOOL` now translates to `bool`, which is a proper boolean type. But historically, it was just a `signed char`, and subject to all of the caveats we see discussed below.

Answer (score 17):

The problem is that BOOL is not a native type, but a typedef:

```
typedef signed char      BOOL;

#define YES             (BOOL)1
#define NO              (BOOL)0
```

As a char, its values aren't constrained to `TRUE` and `FALSE`.  What happens with another value?

```
BOOL b = 42;
if (b)
{
    // true
}
if (b != YES)
{
    // also true
}
```

Comment: yeah ok, but that's the coder's fault if he sets his BOOL vars to some arbitrary values because he's a lazy hacker.

Comment: @jrk: or the coder's coworker did, or the codebase's previous maintainer, or a developer for a library used in the project...  It never hurts to be paranoid.

Comment: @jsz: I know this is a super old question, but settting a `BOOL` with something like `bitMask & (1 << 2)` is a perfectly reasonable thing to do, and can produce an "arbitrary" truthy value (at least one bit set) that isn't equal to `YES` (just LSB set). See [`BOOL`'s sharp corners](http://blog.bignerdranch.com/564-bools-sharp-corners/) at BNR for more.

Answer (score 11):

You should never compare booleans against *anything* in any of the C based languages. The right way to do it is to use either:

```
if (b)
```

or:

```
if (!b)
```

This makes your code much more readable (especially if you're using intelligently named variables and functions like `isPrime(n)` or `childThreadHasFinished`) and safe. The reason something like:

```
if (b == TRUE)
```

is not so safe is that there are actually a large number of values of `b` which will evaluate to true, and `TRUE` is only one of them.

Consider the following:

```
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE  1

int flag = 7;
if (flag)         printf ("number 1\n");
if (flag == TRUE) printf ("number 2\n");
```

You should get *both* those lines printed out if it were working as expected but you only get the first. That's because 7 *is* actually true if treated correctly (0 is false, everything else is true) but the explicit test for equality evaluates to false.

*Update:*

In response to your comment that you thought there'd be more to it than coder stupidity: yes, there is (but I still wouldn't discount coder stupidity as a good enough reason - defensive programming is always a good idea).

I also mentioned readability, which is rather high on my list of desirable features in code.

A *condition* should either be a comparison between objects or a flag (including boolean return values):

```
if (a == b) ...
if (c > d) ...
if (strcmp (e, "Urk") == 0) ...
if (isFinished) ...
if (userPressedEsc (ch)) ...
```

If you use (what I consider) an abomination like:

```
if (isFinished == TRUE) ...
```

where do you stop:

```
if (isFinished == TRUE) ...
if ((isFinished == TRUE) == TRUE) ...
if (((isFinished == TRUE) == TRUE) == TRUE) ...
```

and so on.

The *right* way to do it for readability is to just use appropriately named flag variables.

Comment: yeah ok, but if I am using a BOOL variable then I won't set it to anything different than YES or NO. it's like comparing unsigned with signed and crying because weird stuff happens.

I thought that there might be another reason than the programmer's stupidity not comparing BOOL.

Comment: Yes, there's readability as well. Booleans should be of the form "something == something", "something < something" and so on if you're actually comparing things. A *flag* should be named appropriately (finishedLoop, gotUserData, ...) so that you can just use "if (flag)". The "if (flag == TRUE)" construct is an abomination in terms of readability since that's just another check. Is that where you stop or do you keep going: "if ((flag == TRUE) == TRUE)", "if (((flag == TRUE) == TRUE) == TRUE)", ad infinitum (reduction ad absurdum). :-)

Answer (score 2):

All this is true, but there are valid counter arguments that might be considered:

— Maybe we *want* to check a BOOL is actually YES or NO. Really, storing any other value than 0 or 1 in a BOOL is pretty incorrect. If it happens, isn't it more likely because of a bug somewhere else in the codebase, and isn't not explicitly checking against YES just masking this bug? I think this is way more likely than a sloppy programmer using BOOL in a non-standard way. So, I think I'd *want* my tests to fail if my BOOL isn't YES when I'm looking for truth.

— I don't necessarily agree that "if (isWhatever)" is more readable especially when evaluating long, but otherwise readable, function calls,

e.g. compare

```
if ([myObj doThisBigThingWithName:@"Name" andDate:[NSDate now]]) {}
```

with:

```
if (![myObj doThisBigThingWithName:@"Name" andDate:[NSDate now]]) {}
```

The first is comparing against true, the second against false and it's hard to tell the difference when quickly reading code, right?

Compare this to:

```
if ([myObj doThisBigThingWithName:@"Name" andDate:[NSDate now]] == YES) {}
```

and

```
if ([myObj doThisBigThingWithName:@"Name" andDate:[NSDate now]] == NO) {}
```

…and isn't it much more readable?

Again, I'm not saying one way is correct and the other's wrong, but there are some counterpoints.

Comment: If readability is the main concern, you could use a macro: #define NOT(x) (!(x))

Answer (score 0):

When the code uses a `BOOL` variable, it is supposed to use such variable as a boolean. The compiler doesn't check if a `BOOL` variable gets a different value, in the same way the compiler doesn't check if you initialize a variable passed to a method with a value taken between a set of constants.