# Why do nonzero numbers fail to set a BOOL property to YES?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bitmask

It is my understanding that in Objective C, which is based off of C, all BOOLs are basically shorts (-127 to 128), with zero being the only value for "FALSE", or "NO". However, when I recently tried to set a button's selected value based off of a bitmask, it fails. Why?

```
NSInteger bitfield = 127;
NSInteger bitmask = 1 << 6; // 64

myButton.selected = bitfield & bitmask; // selected will remain NO
```

Comment: C don't have `bool`, C++ does. And C++ enforces that a `bool` type can be only 0 or 1. Assigning other positive numbers to it will convert its value to 1 automatically. I don't know about Objective-C but maybe you are facing something in this order.

Comment: It's not that I don't believe you, but I don't believe you.  Though it would inspire more confidence if you did `myButton.selected = !!(bitfield & bitmask);`

Comment: Havenard: Allow me to clarify: I am talking about programming in Objective C.

Hot: I can fix it with something like this:
    myButton.selected = (bitfield & bitmask) != 0;

What I want to know is WHY the nonzero values aren't evaluated as YES.

Comment: @Havenard C **does have `bool`.**

Comment: And Objective-C has `BOOL`.

Comment: @HotLicks Why don't you believe him? `BOOL` is not `bool`, thus it doesn't work like a true boolean value.

Comment: @H2CO3 - What I don't believe is that it isn't working.  BOOL is (I forget) a byte or int, and will be treated as YES if non-zero.

Comment: @H2CO3 Last I checked pure C don't have `bool` and never had. Where did you see that?

Comment: In all seriousness, I suggest that you act as if the answer is unknowable and use YES and NO as the entire set of values that a BOOL can take.  Your programs will be easier to understand six months down the road.

Comment: @Havenard In the C99 standard, in first place.

Comment: @PhillipMills - It's quite common to use bit masks as the OP is doing, and it should be working, from what I can tell.  (But, as I indicated earlier, it would be best to convert the value to a canonical BOOL before assigning.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [comparing BOOL against YES](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934580/comparing-bool-against-yes)

Comment: @HotLicks ...resulting in the above type of confusion.  :)

Comment: I know I can convert the value to a BOOL value. The question is academic. I just want to understand why "1" is the only "YES" condition it accepts. It should be the other way around, with "0" being the only "NO" condition...

Comment: GoldenJoe, do this: `NSLog(@"selected is %s", myButton.selected ? "YES" : "NO");`.  The problem could be that some consumers of `selected` are in turn (and somewhat inappropriately) doing `&` and `|` operations with it, rather than using `&&` and `||`.  (Or doing `== YES`, etc.)

Comment: `UIControl` has an instance variable `unsigned int selected:1`. My test showed that assigning a value to the "selected" property just assigns the least significant bit to this bit field. For example, `self.myButton.selected = 3; NSLog(@"%d", self.myButton.selected);` prints `1`.

Comment: @MartinR So that behaves "erroneously" (=in an unexpected manner) too. `64 == 0`, modulo 2.

Comment: @MartinR Nice find, by the way.

Comment: @MartinR - What happens if you assign 6 instead of 3?

Comment: @HotLicks: Then you get 0 back. It seems that the passed value is simply stored in _controlFlags.selected, which is an instance variable of UIControl and is an bitfield of size 1.

Comment: @MartinR - If so that seems buggish to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `BOOL` is not `bool`.

`BOOL` is a just a non-standard (Objective-C-specific) typedef for a (non-`bool`) integral type (as far as I know, it's always `signed char` but I might be wrong). As such, it does **not** behave as a true Boolean data type, but rather as its underlying integral type. So, if you assign `64` to it, it will store 64 (and not `true` or `1`). It is possible that, as a result of this, an operation that always assumes the `true` value to be 1 (i. e. the LSB set) will fail to recognize 64 as such.

In contrast, if you replaced `BOOL` with the true C99 Boolean type, which is `_Bool` or `bool`, then you would experience the expected behavior. I. e., assigning **any non-zero value** to the variable would have it store `true` or `1`, regardless to whether that value was really 1.

Comment: Spot on. The key piece of this answer is "an operation that always assumes the true value to be 1 (i. e. the LSB set) will fail to recognize 64". Never evaluate a `BOOL` other than by comparison to `0` (which is implicit for a conditional -- either `if(myBool)` or `myBool ? ... : ...`).

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yes, exactly.

Comment: So is this an error in the OP's code (because you "have to" assign YES or NO to myButton.selected), or an error in the implementation of the "selected" property (which just stores the LSB in a bitfield of size 1, as mentioned above) ?

Comment: @MartinR I'd say an error in OP's code, but **much rather an error in his assumptions.**

Comment: @H2CO3 It isn't Apple specific.  `BOOL` dates back to the creation of Objective-C and may likely pre-date `bool`.  It was created when ObjC was *merely* a C-Preprocessor extension + runtime.  Thus, adding new types to the compiler that had new rules (like enforced YES/NO values) was prohibitively difficult (if not impossible).   And, yes, it is a PITA.  Fixing it is a bigger PITA because there have always been significant codebases that would break and there weren't the resources/time to fix when the compiler was being rev'd.

Comment: @bbum Should I then `s/Apple/Objective-C/`?

Comment: @bbum Oh, and I was not trying to criticize the design decisions behind `BOOL`. If I was writing a framework that defined its own Boolean type (why? that's another question...), then I'd probably just go ahead and `typedef int MyBool` or something.

Comment: Yeah -- BOOL pre-dates NeXT, IIRC (but I may not be IIRC-ing :).

Comment: @bbum Thanks, done. "Fortunately", the 'non-standard' part stays true -- *IIRC* there's no standards document for Objective-C (I wish there was one).

Comment: @H2CO3 It is worthy of criticism, but the history sheds light on the context of the decision.   If it had been a decision made in, say, 2002, then it would be worthy of berating vociferously. :)