# Sort array according to boolean property

Tags: swift, sorting, swift2

I'm having an array of objects. Every objects has a property `isUser: Bool`. So now I want to sort that array that the objects with the `isUser == true` are first in the array and then the objects with `isUser == false`.

Do I need to filter for both `true` and `false` and then concatenate the two arrays or can this be done simpler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it myself. It is possible with the following:

```
self.objectsOfFoo.sortInPlace { $0.isUser && !$1.isUser}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extend `Bool` to make it comparable: treat `true == 1` and `false == 0`. The advantage is that your code becomes much easier to read:

```
extension Bool: Comparable {}

public func < (lhs: Bool, rhs: Bool) -> Bool {
    return Int(lhs) < Int(rhs)
}

self.objectsOfFoo.sortInPlace { $0.isUser > $1.isUser }
```

Comment: Therein lies madness. Using integers as true and false values in C and other languages has resulted in numerous problems for various reasons. One big one is that the concept of false being less than true is an arbitrary decision and doesn't have any real bearing on a Boolean value. The best way to handle it is to use the existing logical operators to test for `true` or `false`. Making `Bool` `Comparable` is an unnecessary and confusing hack.

Comment: It's not confusing if it has been that way for 40 yeas since the original C

Comment: Major bugs in C et. al. have been found whose cause was comparing integers instead of boolean values. This is less likely in your example but it's still a good coding practice to avoid unnecessary operator overloading. Especially when the concept of true and false doesn't really lend itself to a natural "less than" operator. There are boolean operators that can handle the task just fine, use those instead.

Comment: Citation please. Otherwise it's a straw man argument. BTW, C doesn't have bool until C99. And to this day, `true` and `false` are still mapped to 1 and 0. Any C book worth the paper it's printed on would have mentioned that. The question in this case is to give an order to boolean values. Which is exactly what I did. I find this debate much ado about nothing

Comment: There are many: https://markshroyer.com/2012/06/c-both-true-and-false/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934580/is-comparing-a-bool-against-yes-dangerous https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/bools-sharp-corners/ http://www.andromeda.com/people/ddyer/topten.html - although none are exactly what you're doing it's simply best to avoid it if you can.

Comment: These are not bugs in production software but edge cases. If you want to shoot yourself in the foot, C will provide plenty of ammo. This debate is getting silly. Let's just agree to disagree

Answer (score 2):

You can sort `Array` In `Swift 3.0` something like below.I have tried with my `Bool` property in `Swift 3.0`

```
yourArray.sort { (item1, item2) -> Bool in
                     var check1: Int = 0
                     var check2: Int = 0
                     if item1.isUser != nil, item1.isUser == true {
                        check1 = 1
                     }
                     if item2.isUser != nil, item2.isUser == true {
                        check2 = 1
                     }
                     return check1 > check2
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

sorted() will return the sorted array on the basis of bool property without changing contents.

```
let sortedArray = unsortedArray.sorted(by:{ !$0.isUser && $1.isUser})
```