# gomobile: error return values on iOS have both NSError and boolean return

Tags: go, gomobile

When using gobind via gomobile on iOS for an interface type, a golang function returning an `error` results in 2 impacts to the class in Objective C (example below):

- The inclusion of a NSError pointer passed in
- The method returns a boolean

I can infer how to use the NSError pointer, it's a standard objective C practice. But what value should I be returning for the boolean? TRUE on error, FALSE on success? The opposite? Something else? I can't seem to find documentation anywhere.

#### Example

An interface like this:

```
type A interface {
  DoThing(data *DataType) error
}
```

Get's an objective C interface like this:

```
@interface PackageA : NSObject <goSeqRefInterface, PackageA> {
}
@property(strong, readonly) _Nonnull id _ref;
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithRef:(_Nonnull id)ref;

// Important bit is here:
- (BOOL)doThing:(data* _Nullable)DataType error:(NSError* _Nullable* _Nullable)error;
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Objective-C, it is standard for methods that perform actions which might result in an error to return a boolean indicating success or failure, [with `YES` for success and `NO` for failure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/690903/6309), and to accept an [`NSError **` parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9389502/6309) to provide error details when necessary.

Applying this to the code generated by [`gomobile`](https://github.com/golang/mobile) and [`gobind`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gobind), you should handle the boolean return value in the same way.

For your Go interface:

```golang
type A interface {
  DoThing(data *DataType) error
}
```

`gomobile` will generate an Objective-C interface like (as you mention):

```objectivec
@interface PackageA : NSObject
- (BOOL)doThingWithData:(DataType *)data error:(NSError **)error;
@end
```

```bash
[ Go Interface ]          [ Gomobile Binding ]        [ Obj-C Interface ]
    A (DoThing)   --->      gobind (error)     --->   PackageA (doThing:error:)
```

An Objective-C method would then be:

```objectivec
- (BOOL)doThingWithData:(DataType *)data error:(NSError **)error {
    BOOL success = your-operation(); // Attempt to do the thing
    if (!success) {
        // An error occurred, populate the error if it is not NULL
        if (error != NULL) {
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"YourErrorDomain"
                                         code:YourErrorCode
                                     userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: @"An error occurred"}];
        }
        return NO; // Return NO to indicate failure
    }
    return YES; // Return YES to indicate success
}
```

In this pattern, `gomobile` follows the same conventions as Apple's Objective-C methods, which is to return a boolean value indicating the success of the operation, with an optional `NSError` to detail any errors that occurred.

Comment: Makes perfect sense and follows standard patterns. If there was an authoritative source (docs or source) added that would be great, but I think you got it.

Comment: @scosman I agree, I have found only reference to other Stack Overflow answer and not an official documentation.